# Ansible raw & quoting

Tags: mysql, escaping, quotes, ansible

What is the correct way to achive a mysql request with the Ansible raw module ?

```
ansible host -m raw -a 'mysql mydb -e "SELECT lastname FROM table WHERE fistname = 'Joe'"' --su -vvvv
```

this doesn't work and give me the following output

```
<host> 
<host> PubkeyAuthentication=no ConnectTimeout=10 'su  root -c "$SHELL -c '"'"'echo SUDO-SUCCESS-sbqanpltaxkqfzxjdnpjytpnytyhrvow; mysql mydb -e "SELECT lastname FROM table WHERE firstname=Joe"'"'"'"' GSSAPIAuthentication=no User=user ControlPath=/home/user/.ansible/cp/ansible-ssh-%h-%p-%r ControlMaster=auto ControlPersist=60s
host | FAILED | rc=1 >>

value: -c: line 0: unexpected EOF while looking for matching `''
value: -c: line 1: syntax error: unexpected end of file
debug3: mux_client_read_packet: read header failed: Broken pipe
debug2: Received exit status from master 1
Shared connection to host closed.


ERROR 1054 (42S22) at line 1: Unknown column 'firstname' in 'where clause'
```

Then if I try to escape :

```
ansible host -m raw -a 'mysql mydb -e \"SELECT lastname FROM table WHERE fistname = 'Joe'\"'
```

Ansible removes singles quotes inside the command giving this output :

```
<host> 
<host> PubkeyAuthentication=no ConnectTimeout=10 GSSAPIAuthentication=no   User=user 'su  root -c "$SHELL -c '"'"'echo SUDO-SUCCESS-dmbzdeiqiygmuoebxlswxfzdaxxutgqp; mysql mydb -e \"SELECT value FROM table WHERE firstname=Joe\"'"'"'"' ControlPath=/home/user/.ansible/cp/ansible-ssh-%h-%p-%r ControlMaster=auto ControlPersist=60s
host | FAILED | rc=1 >>
ERROR 1054 (42S22) at line 1: Unknown column 'firstname' in 'where clause'
debug3: mux_client_read_packet: read header failed: Broken pipe
debug2: Received exit status from master 1
Shared connection to host closed.
```

Answer (score 0):

According to the Ansible documentation, [the raw module](http://docs.ansible.com/raw_module.html) is used for executing "a low-down and dirty SSH command" and should only be used in a couple of very specific cases. Given what the documentation states, you shouldn't be using this module at all for trying to invoke mysql.

What you probably want to do is use the [command](http://docs.ansible.com/command_module.html) (or [shell](http://docs.ansible.com/shell_module.html)) module:

```
$ ansible -i ./hosts localhost -m command -a 'mysql -u user -ppass -h mydbhost -e "show databases"'
```

I just tried this and it worked as expected.

Comment: My question was essentially about quoting issue and raw module or shell act the same way in this purpose. The thing is raw module is faster than shell and command modules for dirty commands on tons of hosts.

In fact I found a solution with my quoting problem and I will post it soon.